# Problems creating a header in itextsharp with multiply calls to the table

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have three static PdfPTable methods that are called from the main method used to create a PDF document.

In each method I use PdfPCells' to add data and structure to the tables, so the first PdfPTable method would be to create the header for every page the second is to create the body of the that page and the third is to create the footer for every page. Then the table are added to the PdfPDocument after they are called in the main method

I have tried to use table.HeaderRows = 1 to add a header to every page but when added to the PdfPTable method for the header, it removes everything in that table. When I add it to the the PdfPTable for the body it moves the content on the second page to the bottom of the first page and copies the content of the first page to the second.

```
 //table method for call header
 PdfPTable table = CreateTable(textUpperData/*, document, writer*/);
 document.Add(table);

 //table method call for body
 table = CreateTable1(imgInfoData, posData, sizeData, document);
 document.Add(table);

 //table method call for footer
 table = CreateTable2(textLowerData);
 document.Add(table);

 document.Close();



//header table static method                
    private static PdfPTable CreateTable(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> textUpper/*, Document document, PdfWriter writer*/)
    {
        //SiteDB sitedb = new SiteDB();
        //sitedb.GetEmailText();

        iTextSharp.text.Font headerFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Time New Roman", 14, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        iTextSharp.text.Font bodyFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Time New Roman", 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
        table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        table.WidthPercentage = 100;
        table.TotalWidth = 597.6f;
        table.LockedWidth = true;
        table.SetWidths(new float[] { 1, 2, 1 });

        iTextSharp.text.Image logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Images\\image0.tiff");
        logo.ScaleToFit(150, 235);
        logo.SetAbsolutePosition(595.2f - 150f, 0);


        PdfPCell logoCell = new PdfPCell(logo);
        logoCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
        logoCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        table.AddCell(logoCell);

        Chunk logoChunk = new Chunk(System.Environment.NewLine);
        Phrase logoPhrase = new Phrase(logoChunk);

        //Chunk headerChunk = new Chunk(sitedb.header_lit.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine, headerFont);
        //Phrase headerPhrase = new Phrase(headerChunk);
        Chunk headerChunk = new Chunk(textUpper[0].Key.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine, headerFont);
        Phrase headerPhrase = new Phrase(headerChunk);

        //Chunk bodyChunk = new Chunk(sitedb.body_lit.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine, bodyFont);
        //Phrase bodyPhrase = new Phrase(bodyChunk);
        Chunk bodyChunk = new Chunk(textUpper[0].Value.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine, bodyFont);
        Phrase bodyPhrase = new Phrase(bodyChunk);


        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
        paragraph.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
        paragraph.Add(headerPhrase);
        paragraph.Add(bodyPhrase);


        PdfPCell headerBodyCell = new PdfPCell(paragraph);
        headerBodyCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
        headerBodyCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
        headerBodyCell.Colspan = 2;
        headerBodyCell.PaddingLeft = 5f;
        headerBodyCell.PaddingRight = 5f;
        headerBodyCell.PaddingTop = 8f;
        headerBodyCell.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
        table.AddCell(headerBodyCell);

        return table;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that headers cannot be added to every new page in a pdf which is built from multiple tables, only single tables with cells!

I will most likely create a method that keeps adding a particular table for every new page!

Comment: What type of headers are you trying to display: [1] **page**; common to every page in the document, or [2] **table**; unique to the table and displayed when the table's content spans more than one page.

Comment: I trying to display page headers, I figure it out the above post has the details

Comment: You should use a [PdfPageEventHelper](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPageEventHelper.html).Here's some [sample code](http://kuujinbo.info/cs/itext_img_hdr.aspx).

Comment: Hey kuujinbo, I having a problem with the code you referred to me. The header is not coming up, any idea. Do you want me to post the new code?

Comment: Just release that your example does not include a second table to hold paragraph p, so I'm back in the beginning again. Thanks for the help kuujinbo!

Comment: I don't get it - why do you need a *second* table? You're just trying to create *page headers*, right? A page header can only fit in the (small) area/space allocated to [Document.TopMargin](http://goo.gl/wJZQY). In other words, the space you have for a page header is limited. Maybe we are talking about different things?

Comment: I thought the editing the  tables would be easier but in the end it was too much trouble. So I did a table with cells!